# CrystalReportSource binding

Tags: crystal-reports, filestream

Hello I have a crystalReportViewer and CrystalReportSource on a web form.

I need to be able to bind the reportSource at run time to different report files.

I have the file data stored in a blob in a DB.

The mechanism I am using now is to save the blob to a file and then

this.CrystalReportSource1.Report.FileName = myFileName;

The issue is that I want to avoid saving the file on disk and somehow bind the report directly to a file stream.

Is that possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In C#, I believe that you should be able to use something like the following, but I haven't tested it out on my system.

```
ReportDocument rpt = new ReportDocument();
rpt.Load(filestream); //filestream is your filestream object
```

Give it a try and let me know if you have issues.